# Implementing page hits in haskell web server

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, counter

Let's take the simplest http server in haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai (responseLBS, Application)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)

main = do
    let port = 3000
    putStrLn $ "Listening on port " ++ show port
    run port app

app :: Application
app req f =
    f $ responseLBS status200 [(hContentType, "text/plain")] "Hello world!"
```

How would I integrate a state monad inside the app function that will maintain the page hits? I'm having a difficult time thinking in terms of pure functional language. Maybe I'm missing some basics

Comment: from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.2/docs/src/Network-Wai.html#Application) it shows that ```Application``` appears to operate inside the ```IO``` monad. You could take a look into Monad Transformers and see how they can help you. Also, haskell is a functional language, yes, but what you are describing is a side effect. Prepare to enter 'Monad land' :-)

Comment: yes agreed monad is definitely needed :) let me take a look at monad transformer

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, WAI will invoke the `Application` once per request, and the type of the `Application` is quite constrained: `Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`. The concreteness of the `Application` type means that you can't "lift" `run` to take a function returning `StateT s IO ResponseReceived`, which would be the obvious way to do what you were thinking of. If you wanted to use a `State` monad inside one request handler, you would do it by writing your code to use something like `StateT s IO ResponseReceived` and then using `app req f = runStateT initial $ ...`.  However, this won't work to preserve state between invocations of the request handler, like you seem to want.  Unfortunately, I don't believe that there's really a simple way to have your WAI handlers run in a custom monad and have WAI servers preserve the monadic state between invocations---which in some ways makes sense, since it seems reasonable to expect that a server may want to run the same handler multiple times in parallel for different requests.

Instead, if you want to track some state from inside your handlers, you are probably better off using some kind of mutable state in IO. For example, a simple request counter could be something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai (responseLBS, Application)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
    let port = 3000
    putStrLn $ "Listening on port " ++ show port
    hitCounter <- newMVar 0
    run port $ app hitCounter

app :: MVar Int -> Application
app hitCounter req f = do
    old <- takeMVar hitCounter
    let new = old + 1
    putMVar hitCounter $! new -- Thanks to Daniel Wagner in the comments for $!
    putStrLn $ "Hits: " ++ show new
    f $ responseLBS status200 [(hContentType, "text/plain")] "Hello world!"
```

There are of course a number of other options for concurrent mutable state in Haskell, including `IORef`s, and the various `STM` types. Each of these has advantages/disadvantages/pitfalls that it is important to be aware of in the general context of concurrency/mutable state, and many of them should be usable in this context. Thanks to Daniel Wagner for pointing out in the comments that the original version of this example, which used `putMVar hitCounter new` ignored a common pitfall: if the value put into an `MVar` is not forced, a thunk can build up instead, which is often not what is intended. In the above code, `new` is forced by the `putStrLn`, but in case this is later removed, it is good practice to immediately force a value when putting it into an `MVar`---which the `$!` in the new version (above) does.

Comment: You are printing the hit counter here, which forces the value of `new`. So that's good. But to be robust to future refactorings that may not immediately log the hit counter, it is good practice to `putMVar hitCounter $! new` so that you don't accidentally store a deeply-nested thunk in `hitCounter`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh, oops! Thanks for pointing that out. If you don't mind, one of us could add that as an edit to the answer pointing out the issue.

Comment: Of course, please add it in any way that seems sensible to you.